# In excel, how do I check a long list of names, compared to another list of names, to find missing names

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to check a long list of names, and verify they appear in a second list.

If the name doesn't appear, this confirms I have a missing file.

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

With one list in Sheet1, column A, the other list in Sheet2, column A, use this formula in sheet1 column B, starting in B2 and copied down (row 1 contains labels)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A2),"","missing")
```

Countif will return a zero (= FALSE) when the value is not found. If a value exists, Countif will return a number (= TRUE).

You can also use Match() but Countif is faster.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"missing","")
```